# How to focus a webview by default in flutter?

Tags: flutter, webview

I would focus as soon as possible an input inside a webview when this webview successfully finished to load.

The code to select the input and focus it work but it require only one thing : USER SHOULD click on the webview to make her 'active' / 'focused'. Webview cannot request focus if she is not focused: document.hasFocus.

How to focus by default the webview to let me programmatically set the focus on a specific webview input ?

Comment: Did you find any way @Eng

Comment: not yet @Pushpendra :/